# java: ClassCastException when upcasting Animation to CustomAnimation

Tags: java, android, android-animation, classcastexception

I have a class that extends android.view.Animation:

```
package diffusi.on.com.fifteen_puzzle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

public class CustomAnimation extends Animation {

    private boolean _isLast = false;

    private View _currentTarget = null;

    public interface AnimationListener {
        void onAnimationEnd(CustomAnimation animation);
        void onAnimationRepeat(CustomAnimation animation);
        void onAnimationStart(CustomAnimation animation);
    }

    public static void animateSetOfViews(
            View[] viewsSet, 
            int animResId, 
            int[] startTimeOffsets,
            Context context,
            AnimationListener animationListener
        ) {
        CustomAnimation animation;
        int startTimeOffset; 
        boolean isLastAnim;

        for (int intA = 0; intA < viewsSet.length; intA++) {
            isLastAnim = intA == viewsSet.length - 1;
            animation = (CustomAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, animResId);
            if (intA <= startTimeOffsets.length - 1) {
                startTimeOffset = startTimeOffsets[intA];
            } else startTimeOffset = 0;
            animation.applyToView(viewsSet[intA], startTimeOffset, isLastAnim, animationListener);
        }
    }

    public CustomAnimation() {

    }

    public CustomAnimation(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public boolean isLast() {
        return this._isLast;
    }

    public View getCurrentTarget() {
        return this._currentTarget;
    }

    private void applyToView(View view, int startTimeOffset, boolean isLast, AnimationListener listener) {
        this._isLast = isLast;
        this._currentTarget = view;
        this.setStartOffset(startTimeOffset);
        this.setAnimationListener((Animation.AnimationListener) listener);
        this._currentTarget.startAnimation(this);
    }

}
```

It compiles in IDE without errors. But in runtame, it throws an exception (ClassCastEcxeption) on line: 
animation = (CustomAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, animResId)

Why does I can't upcast Animation instance to my CustomAnimation, which extends Animation ?

Comment: Can you post the method loadAnimation.

Comment: I could add to log result of AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, animResId) and see why this problem happens.

Answer (score 3):

It's not *upcasting*, it is *downcasting*. Upcasting would be of the form `CustomAnimation` to `Animation`.

Presumably `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation` returns a reference to an object which *isn't* actually a `CustomAnimation` - so you can't cast to it. You can only cast to a type when the actual type of the object at execution time is compatible with the type you're casting to. For example:

```
Object x = new Integer(10);
String y = (String) x; // Bang - invalid cast

Object a = "Foo";
String b = (String) a; // This is fine
```

Comment: Thanks. mistake in terminology